# complex DB modelling in firestore

Tags: android, database-design, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a database in firestore . I don't have much idea about noSQL. I have multiple fields of type A , for each of them , I should map it to an array of type B , and each of B has to map to a key-value map . How can anyone help me out in  creating this type of modelling in firestore ?

Example: If you are still not clear, here is my visualization of how my data has to be stored

```
Class 1 ->Student A  -> height of A : x
                     -> weight of A : y
                     -> marks of A : z
        ->Student B  -> height of B : a
                     -> weight of B : b
                     -> marks of B : c

Class 2 ->Student D -> ...
```

Can anyone at least recommend some blog or tutorials for complex DB modelling in firestore..? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That said: you can't really go wrong with [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to me relatively simple.

```
Collection "Class 1" 
       -> Document "UserId" 
          -> Document Field "Name"
          -> Document Field "Weight"
          -> Document Field "Marks"
           ....
       -> Document "UserId" 
          -> Document Field "Name"
          -> Document Field "Weight"
          -> Document Field "Marks"
           ....
//Second class will be a different collection

Collection "Class 2" 
       -> Document "UserId" 
          -> Document Field "Name"
          -> Document Field "Weight"
          -> Document Field "Marks"
           ....
       -> Document "UserId" 
          -> Document Field "Name"
          -> Document Field "Weight"
          -> Document Field "Marks"
           ....
```

But if you are creating something like a school then this is still valid but you could have other queries in front to keep the database more structured. Example:

```
Collection "SchoolName"
      -> Document "Classes"
          -> Collection "Class Name"
              -> Document Attendee "UserId"
                    -> Document Fields "Name"
                    -> Document Fields "Weight"
                           ...
              -> Document Attendee "UserId2"
                    -> Document Fields "Name2"
                    -> Document Fields "Weight2"
```